# Smoothness of the exponential map at the origin

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Let $(M, g)$ be a smooth Riemannian manifold, $p \in M$, and $\exp_P$ the exponential map at the point $P$:
$\exp_P: T(P) \to M$

It seems clear to me that $\exp_P$ is smooth on $U \setminus \{0\}$, where $U$ is a neighborhood of the origin $0 \in T(P)$, because $\exp_P$ is defined from the geodesics, which are solutions of a system of ordinary differential equations.

But is it true that $\exp_P$ is also always smooth at the origin $0 \in T(P)$?

I am not interested for the moment on the ways to calculate these high order derivatives, but just on the theoretical question about their existence.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes it is, and there is more: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss's_lemma_(Riemannian_geometry)

Comment: If I am right, concerning the differentiability properties of the exponential map, Gauss'lemma tells you only that the exponential map has first order derivatives at the origine(that is: the identity), but it tells you nothing about high order derivatives.

Comment: Why doesn't the normal argument for smooth dependence on initial conditions work at zero?

Comment: Please use TeX on this site.

Comment: I think that the usual argument for smooth dependence on initial conditions does not work at zero just because the notion of a geodesic with the zero vector as initial tangent vector has no meaning. It is not a legitimate initial condition for the equation of geodesics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Thomas Rot already suggested: this follows directly from smooth dependence of ODEs on initial conditions.

Let $p \in M$ and denote by $\Phi^t\colon TM \to TM$ the geodesic flow. Then the exponential map at $p \in M$ is defined as the time one geodesic flow, restricted to $T_p M$ and projected onto $M$, i.e.
$$
  \exp_p = \pi \circ \Phi^1|_{T_p M} \colon T_p M \to M
$$
where $\pi$ is the tangent bundle projection.

In local coordinates around $p$ this amounts to an ODE on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ involving the Christoffel symbols, and these are smooth since $(M,g)$ was assumed smooth.

**Edit added:** In local coordinates the geodesic flow is given by
$$
  \dot{x}^i = v^i, \qquad \dot{v}^i = -\Gamma^i_{jk}(x) v^j v^k
$$
with $(x,v) \in \mathbb{R}^{2n}$ induced local coordinates on $T M$.
This is well-defined, also for $v = 0$.

Comment: Please, cf. my last answer to Thomas Rot. I think that this argument is correct for every vector in Tp, except the zero vector. Because you cannot write a geodesic equation with zero as initial condition for the tangent vector.

Comment: @Julien: Why not? The ODE in local coordinates is perfectly well-defined, also for $0 \in T_p M$. Actually, the solution is immediately seen to be the constant curve, or point, $(p,0) \in T M$, hence $\exp_p(0) = p$.

Comment: Thank you Jaap Eldering. It did not see before that a constant curve could be considered as a degenerate geodesic curve.